# Clojure command line: cursor moves every time I type closing parenthesis

Tags: command-line, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

In the clojure command line

```
user=>
```

Every time I close a parenthesis, the cursor ▌ quickly moves to the opening paren of that block and moves back right away (probably to help me see where I started).

This can quickly get very frustrating when I type fast. How can I turn this option off?

Comment: What is frustrating about it?

Comment: The cursor constantly moving around (not in the direction that I'm typing) gives me a bit of a seizure.

Comment: If you don't have paredit at hand this helps you to close your forms correctly before evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using lein repl, it should be using readline - put the following in ~/.inputrc

`set blink-matching-paren off`

Comment: Awesome. `~/.inputrc` didn't exist so I had to create it!